# euclidean distance matrix

Tags: python, matrix, euclidean-distance

I'd like to calculate Euclidean distance between two words. First of all, each phoneme was vectorised:

```
g = (0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
a = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
k = (0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
n = (0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

So distance between two words, 'gaN' and 'gak', for example, is

```
dst1 = distance.euclidean(g,g)
dst2 = distance.euclidean(a,a)
dst3 = distance.euclidean(N,k)
dist = dst1+dst2+dst3
print(dist)
```

What I'd like to make is a huge matrix that shows all distances between over 800 words. That should look like the table below (as in csv file)

```
    gaN   gak   gan  gal ...
gaN 0     1.73  1.41
gak 1.73  0     2.24
gan 1.41  2.24  0
gal
...
```

Could anyone help me with this? I'm currently using Python but R would be fine, too.

Comment: What have you try so far? Do you have a function to compute euclidean distance between two words? Do you know how to write a matrix to a CSV file? ...

Comment: What exactly is the Euclidean distance between two words? Are you using some module, and if so, which one? Have you written any code, where is it?

Comment: Thank you very much. In Python, I used the built-in function for Euclidean distance (from scipy.spatial import distance) but when I used R I wrote as: euc.dist <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2)). Please note that this is for phonetic distances between two words that consist of vectors of eleven 1s or 0s. I do not know how to write a matrix to csv file just as the last box above.

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean distance can only operate on numeric objects, as you know. I'm not sure what a phenome is, but if you already have numeric representations of all words, then it should be trivial. (in this case, is your problem translating the distance matrix back to the GaN, gak table? if so, more information is needed about how you get from there to the phenome object(s).

As far as converting to csv, that's trivial. You can actually do it with zero additional lines using the excellent `pandas` package:

import pandas as pd
dist=pd.DataFrame(euclidean_distances(tbl1,tbl2)).to_csv('distances.csv')